# sed regular expression part

Tags: regex, sed

Right now I am trying to delete all the lines of the file that has number 80000 or greater at the end of the line

For example

Jennifer Cowan:548-834-2348:583 Laurel Ave., Kingsville, TX 83745:10/1/35:58900
Jon DeLoach:408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086:7/25/53:85100

When I run sed, the command should only delete the line of Jon DeLoach

I tried till

```
sed '/:0*[1-9][0-9]{5,}|:0*[8-9][0-9]{4,}/d' datebook.txt
```

since

```
egrep ':0*[1-9][0-9]{5,}|:0*[8-9][0-9]{4,}' datebook.txt
```

returns all the lines that has 800000 or greater

however, sed command actually does not work and find out that because regular expression that I made

```
 ':0*[1-9][0-9]{5,}|:0*[8-9][0-9]{4,}'
```

only work for egrep not grep

I am new to regular expression and kind of confuse how to change from egrep to grep

Comment: Do you have to use `sed`? This is relatively trivial using `awk`, e.g. `awk -F":" '$NF < 80000' file`

Comment: yes, it is my assignment that we must use the sed

Comment: If this is an assignment from your teacher, it's a trick question. Tell them that sed and regex aren't the proper tools for this and you'll get an A+. Or they'll fail you and tell you that there's a good way to do it, but at least you'll know not to trust this teacher with programming advice anymore.

Comment: I searched through whole internet and everyone says handling the numbers in the reg is not really good idea. Sadly, my assignment forces me to do it and failing would not be my option.

Comment: Well, if you really need to do basic arithmetic with regex, this is what it looks like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/addition-with-sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an awkward question, but you could tweak your existing answer to get:

```
sed '/:[8-9][0-9]\{3,\}$/d; /:[0-9]\{6,\}$/d' file
```

I'm not sure what else you can do with sed (it's pretty fragile); does that solve your problem?

Comment: This solved the problem Thank you! I did not know I have to sepearte the or statement of the reg part

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions do not understand numeric values, and if you do it like this it's going to be a nightmare to maintain.

You are dealing with data that is in fields, so it is a good task for awk.

You want awk to go through all the lines and then print out the ones where the fifth field is less than 80000.

```
awk -F":" '$5 < 80000' datebook.txt
```

The `-F":"` says that a colon is the field separator. `$5` means the fifth field.

Comment: sadly, it would be much easier with the awk. However, my assignment restrict it to use sed only

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Is your teacher telling you to use regular expressions on numeric values? That's very disappointing.

Comment: 3. Remove the employee entry (entries) whose salary (salaries) is greater than 80000. There can be multiple entries whose salaries are greater than 80000. is there way that I can do without reg in sed?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; what sort of expressions other than regular expressions do you hope to use? `sed` basically only understands regular expressions and line numbers, though if you have the stamina, you can build all sorts of higher-order logic on top of that. That's hardly the task here, though.

Comment: sed only understands regular expressions. It does not understand numeric values like awk does. Anything you would do in sed would have to use regular expressions. Regular expressions do not understand numeric values. Trying to determine if a field's value is < 80000 with regular expressions is using the wrong tool for the job. It's like driving nails with a screwdriver instead of a hammer. That's why it's disappointing that you would be given that as a homework assignment.